# How can I specify a string type for an object accessed with bracket notation?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to do:

```
const accessToken: string = req.headers['x-access-token'];
```

but `typescript` complains:

```
Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `as` keyword:

```
const accessToken: string = req.headers['x-access-token'] as string;
```